# Tool or IDE for comfortable AutoHotKey (AHK) macro management?

Tags: windows, automation

Do you know about **tool or [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) which allows comfortable management of [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macros**?
I know many ways how to edit them directly in text file. For example using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). But since I have 200+ macros, this is getting cumbersome so I would like to switch to IDE where I can

- view macros as list (without code behind each)
- reorder macros using drag&drop, delete them
- reload macros to AHK
- create simple macros by typing keystrokes
- get warnings about duplicate hotkeys

The product can be free or up to $50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: No, there's no IDE

but

### Notepad++ with customization comes close

The canonical place to start is the forum thread [Set up Notepad++ for AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=50) which has a gained a mirror [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus). This includes the following IDE-like goodies:

- Basic syntax highlighting.
  *Just works.*
- Autocomplete for built-in function, variable and directive names (e.g. `A_TitleMatchMode`, `#IfWinActive`).
  *Note that the autocomplete list seems to be missing newer v2 constructs like the `#HotIf` directive. (As of this comment in Oct 2023, last update was in Mar 2020)*
- Quickjump hotkey/function/class list.
  *Setup is a bit more involved for this one, but worth the effort if you want to navigate larger collections of hotkeys/hostrings and user-defined functions.*

All that together with a simple `^!r::Reload` rule in your main scriptfile bring the development experience for one's scripts pretty close to a proper IDE.

Duplicate detection could be automated using scripting, or by keeping hotkey definitions sorted, so that identical definitions are bound to be noticed when writing them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a note that I would not recommend mapping Ctrl+Alt to anyone since many programs use it and moreover, all the national keyboards reserve its letter space (Ctrl+AltGr+letter). To minimize interferences, use Ctrl+Alt+Shift. To avoid them even more, create your own modifier key in AHK, for example CapsLock or AppsKey, allowing for example CapsLock+A or AppsKey+A. (Then I also recommend to add a mapping retaining their original function, like CapsLock::CapsLock)

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) also supports [a bunch of plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=autohotkey&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) that make it easier to work with AHK scripts.

Examples:

- [AutoHotkey Plus Plus](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mark-wiemer.vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus) - adds basic language features such as syntax highlighting, autocomplete and all relateed features (IntelliSense), debugging, compilation, formatter, etc.
- [vscode-authohotkey-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zero-plusplus.vscode-autohotkey-debug) - another more advanced debugger
  etc.

[image: Example]